# send workflow emails to supervisor and cc to all corresponding users in CC

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

I have 2 columns in SharePoint list as (Resource email, Supervisor email), test data given below.

```
Resource Email   Supervisor Email  
===================================
AAA    SSS     
BBB    SSS       
CCC    SSS
DDD    TTT
EEE    TTT
```

How to Send workflow emails to supervisor and cc to all corresponding users in CC using SharePoint designer 2013.

When workflow email trigger 2 email should create one with SSS and cc to AAA, BBB,CCC and another email To TTT CC DDD,EEE.

Please help me with this.

Comment: what is the event to trigger worrkflow ? On change of item SSS or TTT or anything else ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am using reminder email for this, Eg: if the status column shows as 'No' then trigger email to supervisor and cc to all tagged resources under that supervisor.

Comment: Check my answer below, basically you have to call HTTP Web Call in SPD workflow, then iterate response and use the response for sending mail.

Comment: sorry for asking more question, as i never used this action, do you have any example for send email via call HTTP web? it would be helpful for reference.

Comment: I assume you are using SharePoint 2013 SPD workflow to send mail ?

Comment: Yes i am using share point designer 2013

Comment: Use - "send mail" action to send mail notification. To get CC value, call HTTP Call action to get Resource Email. Refer this link for http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/58e23e/call-http-web-service-using-sharepoint-designer-2013-spd/

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve Resource email, call REST API on the list and select 'Resource Email' based on 'Supervisor Email'. The REST API will have $select= Resource Email, $filter = Supervisor Email eq 'SSS'.

The response needs to be looped to read the 'Resource Email' column values to create a single string value. Pass the string value in "Send Mail" step.